# How to get a selected value in drop down in configuration module ? (Magento)

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I wrote this two line in a phtml page:

```
$array = Mage::getStoreConfig('extcontacts/extendedcontactsGroup');
var_dump($array);
```

And this is the result:

```
array (size=8)
  'excontactus_select' => string '1' (length=1)
  'defaultrecipient_text' => string 'soufiane.marar1@gmail.com' (length=25)
  'departements_textarea' => string 'Sales Department,sales@example.com
Support Department,support@example.com' (length=74)
  'staticblock_select' => string '1' (length=1)
  'contactfrm_select' => string '0' (length=1)
  'emailsender_select' => string 'general' (length=7)
  'sendcopytosender_select' => string '0' (length=1)
  'emailtemplate_select' => string     'extcontacts_extendedcontacts_group_emailtemplate_select' (length=55)
```

For select it returns 1 or 0 and I don't want 1 or 0 to be returned I want the string.

```
staticblock_select items example = block1,block2,block3...
```

How can I do to make it return the selected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to create your own, Store Config Dropdown class for that select element.
I recommend to read this, there is a detailed description how to do it:
[Link to Custom Store Config settings](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/)

Especially check this part:

```
<?php

class JR_CustomConfigExample_Model_System_Config_Source_Dropdown_Values
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'value' => 'key1',
                'label' => 'Value 1',
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'key2',
                'label' => 'Value 2',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change you system.xml also this part:

```
 <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
```

Without to seeing your full module files, I could help with this one. Hope it helped, to point to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution and this is it :

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {

       $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

       $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

       $query = 'SELECT title FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('cms/block');

       $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

       $monarray = array();
       $compt = 1;

       foreach ($results as $key => $value) { 
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) { 
    the solution    ==> $monarray[$compt-1] = array('value'=>$value2, 
          'label'=>Mage::helper('extendedcontacts')->__($value2));
         $compt++;
        }
      } 
       return $monarray;
    }
```

i changed this line :

```
$monarray[$compt-1] = array('value'=>$compt,'label'=>Mage::helper('extendedcontacts')->__($value2));
```

to this line :

```
$monarray[$compt-1] = array('value'=>$value2,'label'=>Mage::helper('extendedcontacts')->__($value2));
```

and thas the result it returns footer links as example :

```
array (size=8)
  'excontactusSelect' => string '1' (length=1)
  'staticblockSelect' => string 'Footer Links' (length=12)
  'contactfrmSelect' => string '1' (length=1)
  'defaultrecipientText' => string 'soufiane.marar1@gmail.com' (length=25)
  'emailsenderSelect' => string 'general' (length=7)
  'sendcopytosenderSelect' => string '0' (length=1)
  'emailtemplateSelect' => string 'extcontacts_extendedcontactsGroup_emailtemplateSelect' (length=53)
  'departementsTextarea' => string '' (length=0)
```

this is the module conf :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlBfa.png